# Is it possible to cache the auth token to speed up login in Firebase with iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security

I'm authenticating to Firebase with `FirebaseSimpleLogin` and Email/Password authentication in iOS. It seems that making the `[authClient loginWithEmail:username andPassword:password withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAUser *user) { ... }];` takes roughly 5-8 seconds to complete.

Is there a way to speed up the login, like caching the `authToken` from `FAUser`, and using starting to use that directly in the first Firebase call?

**Update:**

It seems that storing the `authToken` after a successful login to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:user.authToken forKey:USERDEFAULTS_LOGIN_TOKEN];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

... and then doing an `authWithCredential:` call with the stored `authToken` on next login attempt:

```
NSString *authToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:USERDEFAULTS_LOGIN_TOKEN];
if (authToken) {
    NSLog(@"Firebase logging in with token...");
    [[Mesh root] authWithCredential:authToken withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, id data) { ...
```

... isn't any faster. Is there another way to speed up the login?

Comment: How slow is this exactly? What sort of profiling are you using and where is the bottleneck?

Comment: When I place the call `[authClient loginWithEmail:...´ it takes roughly 5 to 10 seconds for the `completionBlock` call to execute. What this practically means is that when the application is started after it has been suspended it takes 10-15 seconds before actual data is moving. I'll try to break down this in smaller pieces to actually find out where the lag is (I'm in Finland, and behind a very low-latency, high-bandwith connection, and have tried this in a couple of different networks, so the problem shouldn't be there).

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro Can you email me (michael@firebase.com)?  This is definitely not expected.  The next diagnostic step would be to remove auth form the picture and just monitor .info/connected to see how long it's taking your app to connect to Firebase.  See the second example on https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html

Answer (score 4):

With the release of the Firebase iOS / OS-X Client v1.2.0, Firebase caches the local client authentication state and greatly optimizes the speed of re-authentication. Previous client versions required multiple server roundtrips before the client would enter an "authenticated" state, but this is now immediate if a valid, persisted session has been located on-disk.

Also note that [Firebase Simple Login](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login) has been deprecated and replaced with a reimplementation of Firebase authentication that is enabled in the core Firebase client libraries. Check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html for the guides on how to get started with it on iOS.