# Firebase: Is there way to be more faster for authentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, firebase

Similar to this question. [Is it possible to cache the auth token to speed up login in Firebase with iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463408/is-it-possible-to-cache-the-auth-token-to-speed-up-login-in-firebase-with-ios)

I'm authenticating with FirebaseSimpleLogin. Here is my authentication code

```
- (void)checkAuthStatus{

Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:rootURL];
FirebaseSimpleLogin *authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:ref];

[authClient checkAuthStatusWithBlock:^(NSError *error, FAUser *user)
{
    if (error == nil)
    {

        if (user != nil)
        {

            if(user.thirdPartyUserData == nil){

                 //Email Login


            }else{

                //Facebook、Twitter Login

            }

        }else [self actionLogin];

    }
    else
    {
        NSString *message = [error.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showError:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}];
}
```

I also this method with async blocks

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    [self checkAuthStatus];
});
```

This takes around 5 - 8 seconds until showing tableview data source.
I tried to run iFirefeed app but it takes almost same time.

I want to know more faster way if there is.

Anyone have idea or experience to be more faster for authentication?

Comment: As suggested in the other thread, that's far too slow and there are most likely other contributing factors. Please email support@firebase.com and open a dialog with the devs. Cheers.

Comment: @Kato How fast it should be, then?

Comment: A second or two in particularly slow circumstances should be about the limit of what I would expect. Normally, there's not enough of a delay for me to notice. However, a good deal of this depends on the provider being used (e.g. Facebook logins require contacting Facebook's API and the baggage that comes with that).